# Add Package to Official Repository

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, packaging

I wrote a driver for a remote filesystem (mounts a Google Drive, similar to the way SSHFS mounts a remote server).  It's super useful as an alternative to dropbox or ubuntuone.  It is now getting stable enough to leave my PPA server and be considered for mainstream use.

I would like to have it be considered as a standard apt-get installable package, rather than one that requires manually adding my PPA.  What are the steps required?

Comment: ubuntuone does no longer exist.

Comment: While this is a duplicate, this looks really cool! Could you email it to me with some basic details on how to use it? `0kh_fhgk-lmjtya3`@`mailinator.com`

Comment: Details are available on our site: http://www.gdrivefs.com/